# Ways to Plot Spark Dataframe without Converting it to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

Is there any way to plot information from Spark dataframe without converting the dataframe to pandas?

Did some online research but can't seem to find a way. I need to automatically save these plots as .pdf, so using the built-in visualization tool from databricks would not work.

Right now, this is what I'm doing (as an example):

```py
# df = some Spark data frame 
df = df.toPandas()
df.plot()
display(plt.show())
```

I want to produce line graphs, histograms, bar charts and scatter plots without converting my dataframe to pandas dataframe.
Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

The display function is only available in databricks kernel notebook, not in spark

Answer (score 1):

Just to use `display(<dataframe-name>)` function with a Spark dataframe as the offical document [`Visualizations`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/visualizations/index.html) said as below.

[image]

Then, to select the plot type and change its options as the figure below to show a chart with spark dataframe directly.

[image]

If you want to show the same chart as the pandas dataframe plot of yours, your current way is the only way.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in Jupyter notebooks. Is this answer specifically for Databricks notebooks?

Comment: Yes, it is for Databricks only.

Answer (score 1):

If the spark dataframe 'df' (*as asked in question*) is of type *'pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame'*, then try the following:

```
# Plot spark dataframe
df.column_name.plot.pie()
```

where *column_name* is one of the columns in the spark dataframe 'df'.

You can try finding the type of 'df' by

```
type(df)
```

There are other functions like

*pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.plot.line*

*pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar*

*pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter*

This can be found on the apache spark docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

If the spark dataframe 'df' is of type *'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'*, then try the following:

```
# Import pyspark.pandas
import pyspark.pandas as ps

# Convert pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame to pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame
temp_df = ps.DataFrame( df ).set_index('column_name')

# Plot spark dataframe
temp_df.column_name.plot.pie()
```

**Note:** There could be other better ways to do it as well. If there are kindly suggest them in the comment.